# Camino incompleto

Tags: python

Me pidieron que creara un camino en una matriz de unos y ceros, de un punto dado por el usuario el camino debe ser solo por los ceros, y ademas este camino estar rodeado de ceros igualmente... lo unico que he podido hacer es que verifique que la posicion dada por el usuario sea 0 y este rodeada de ceros.

```
    def Verificar(M,i,j):#M es  la matriz; i,j la coordenada dada por el usuario
    cont=0
    for k in range(i-1,i+2):
        for p in range(j-1,j+2):
            if M[k][p]==0 or M[k][p]==False:
                cont+=1
    if cont==9:
        return 1 #retornara 1 si la posicion es valida
    else:
        return 0 #retornara 0 si la posicion es invalida o erronea
```

esta funcion no admite esquinas que tambien es un error que tengo

Comment: ¿por donde empieza y termina el camino?  ¿Hay un camino garantizado? ¿Cuantos casilleros alrededor hay que examinar para ver si esta "rodeado" (4  u 8)?

Answer (score 1):

Nota: Resolver el problema de encontrar el camino es mucho mayor a lo que has escrito hasta el momento. Es mejor que lo dividas en sub-problemas y vayas consultado cada uno por separado, si es necesario.

Como ayuda, incluyo este código que te muestra como:

1. Recuperar el valor de cada celda sin caerse en los bordes/esquinas.
2. Chequear si una celda está rodeada de ceros. (Estrictamente hablando, chequea que no haya un "1" alrededor. O sea, es como si el mapa estuviera rodeado de ceros.)

Este código está completo. Copialo y juega con él para avanzar en tu problema.

```
from random import randrange

def crear_mapa(dim):
    """ Crea una mapa cuadrado de dim x dim, poblado de ceros y unos al azar.
        Genera tres filas de puros ceros para garantizar que haya al menos un camino.
    """
    mapa = []    
    for fila in range(dim):
        linea = []
        for columna in range(dim):
            linea.append(randrange(2))  # Retorna 0 o 1
        mapa.append(linea)
    
    # Insertar tres filas de ceros
    for fila in range(int(dim / 2 - 1), int(dim / 2 + 2)):
        for columna in range(dim):
            mapa[fila][columna] = 0
    return mapa

def valor_celda(mapa, fila, columna):
    """ Retorna el valor de la celda en fila, columna.
        El valor retornado es 0, 1 o -1 (celda no existe)
    """
    dim = len(mapa)
    if fila in range(dim) and columna in range(dim):
        valor = mapa[fila][columna]
    else:
        valor = -1
    return valor

def chequear_celda(mapa, fila, columna):
    """ Revisa si la celda en fila, columna está rodeada 
        de ceros (que no tenga un "1" alrededor).

        Retorna True si cumple la condición
    """
    for i in range(fila-1,fila+2):
        for j in range(columna-1, columna+2):
            if valor_celda(mapa, i, j) == 1:
                return False
    return True                

'''                
Probemos las funciones construidas.
'''

# Creamos una matriz al azar de dimension 10 x 10
dim = 10
mapa = crear_mapa(dim)

# Imprimimos la matriz para chequear que la funcion valor_celda
# opere correctamente en todos los casos

for fila in range(dim):
    for columna in range(dim):
        print(valor_celda(mapa, fila, columna), end=" ")
    print()

# Recorremos la matriz para comprobar que
# la funcion chequear_celda opere correctamente. 
# (Sabemos que al menos hay tres filas de puros ceros; 
# algo tendra que salir de ahi ...).
        
for fila in range(dim):
    for columna in range(dim):
        if chequear_celda(mapa, fila, columna):
            print("X", end="")  
        else:
            print("_", end="")
    print()
```

Resultado:

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 
__________
__________
__________
XX________
XXXX______
XXXXXXXXXX
_________X
__________
__________
__________
```

Comment: sos grande capo gracias